# How to Launch an Android AppWidget's configuration Activity from another activity?

Tags: android, configuration, android-appwidget

Well this is driving me crazy. I have developed an App-widget. Everything is working fine.

I have a configuration activity which launches every time a widget is added on the home screen and works beautiful. I save the user settings per widget id etc.

The widget has some buttons, one of them launches an activity with about information, the "About Activity".

The "About Activity" has a button which I want to use to launch the configuration activity for the widget id that launched the "About Activity". The reason I want to do that is because I want the user to be able to configure the contents of any instance of my widget without having it removed and added again (in order to launch the configuration activity).

The configuration activity needs the AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID in order to make the job (save the user settings for this specific widgetid) so I must somehow pass this extra when I 'm calling it from another activity. The obvious think to do is this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(context,act_configure.class).putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, ??? ));
```

Now my question is where is the widgetid? I found a million ways to get the widgetids (the array) but not a single clue on how to get the specific widgetid which launched the "About Activity"

Any help about this will make the hours I spent to find a solution, worth something. Thank you in advance.

p.s. Please forgive my English as they are not my native language...

Comment: Well I deserve somekind of badge. It seems I asked the most difficult android appwidgets question...

Comment: Why don't you put the widget id into the intent to start your about activity? So about knows the id and can use it to start configure

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to achieve but I could not find the widget ID. It is only in one place, in the  onUpdate method of the widget provider. So based on this fact and on Cory Chaltron's answer I finally managed to do the job. See comments in the accepted answer and in my answer too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you setting your widget views? I have an app where I iterate over the active widgets and configure set the `RemoteView` there. You could set your widget id in the onClick you are attaching to the "About" button.

```
final AppWidgetManager widgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
final ComponentName widgetName = new ComponentName(this, WidgetProvider.class);

final int[] widgetIds = widgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(widgetName);

for (int widgetId : widgetIds) {
    final RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

    // This is the important part :-D
    remoteViews.findViewById(R.id.your_about_button).setOnClickListener(... a listener to start your about activity that puts the widget id in the extra like you suggest in your question ...);

    widgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
}
```

Comment: I am accepting your answer as it opens my eyes and pointed me to the right direction. However there is a "catch" you have to make the Intent unique in order for this to work if the user has more than one widget instance running. This is why I am posting my answer also just in case someone wants the full solution in hand. Thank you.

Comment: RemoteViews has no findViewById method, and clicks are managed via setOnClickPendingIntent

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Cory Chaltron here is the solution to my problem.

In the widget provider onUpdate method I should create a "unique" intent to pass to the pending intent which handles the launch of the about activity. Because of the way Android compares Intents, passing the WidgetID in the extras IS NOT ENOUGH, you should also pass it as data to the intent in order to be unique. So here is the code:

```
Intent aboutIntent = new Intent(cx, act_about.class);
aboutIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetIds[i]);
// Make this unique for this appWidgetId
aboutIntent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse("customuri://widget/id/"), String.valueOf(widgetID)));
PendingIntent aboutPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(cx, 0, aboutIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.cmdabout, aboutPendingIntent)
```

Although I answer my own question I am not accepting it because it is based on Cory's answer. Thank you all for the help...

Comment: alternatively, `aboutIntent.setData(aboutIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME));` will also work (it encodes the extras as well).

Comment: You would need to parse that into a Uri like this `aboutIntent.setData(Uri.parse(aboutIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));`